Which domains yield a Laurent series at $i \infty$ for holomorphic $f$ when $\lim_{\operatorname{Im} z \rightarrow \infty} f(z)$ exists?
I am a bit embarassed to ask this question but I could not find an answer, neither in some standard complex analysis books nor here on stackexchange. Which domains yield a Laurent series expansion at $i \infty$ when the holomorphic function has a limit there?
More precisely, I am asking this: Consider an open subset $\mathbb{D} \subseteq \mathbb{H} = \{z \in \mathbb{C}: \operatorname{Im} z \geq 0\}$ such that there exists a sequence $(z_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathbb{D}$ with $\operatorname{Im} z_n \rightarrow \infty$. I am interested in sufficient conditions, or better even equivalent characterizations, of those domains $\mathbb{D}$ which have the following property:
If $f: \mathbb{D} \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic and
$$\lim_{\operatorname{Im} z \rightarrow \infty} f(z) \text{ exists} \,,$$
then there exists some $R > 0$ and a sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathbb{C}$ such that
$$
f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{z^n} \qquad \qquad \forall z \in \mathbb{D}\; \text{ with } \operatorname{Im} z > R\,.
$$
What I have tried is considering $g(z) = f(m(z))$ where $m$ is some conformal mapping which turns the upper $\mathbb{D}$ into some bounded domain. But then we have pretty much an equivalent problem: Which domains yield a Taylor expansion around a point on the boundary when the function is holomorphic in the interior and continuous on the boundary.

Please take the trouble to type your title correctly.

I don't see a typo so I assume you find it unclear. I changed it to make it clearer.

$f$ has a Laurent series at complex $\infty$ if and only if it is analytic in a deleted neighbourhood of $\infty$, i.e. in $\{z \in \mathbb C:\; |z| > R\}$ for some $R$.  There is no such thing as "a Laurent series at $i\infty$".
If you want the series to be of the form
$\sum_{n =0}^\infty a_n/z^n$, i.e. the coefficients of positive powers of $z$ in the Laurent series are all $0$,
that says $\lim_{z \to \infty} f(z)$ exists.  A limit as $\text{Im}(z) \to \infty$ is not sufficient, you need a limit as $z \to \infty$, i.e. $|z| \to \infty$.

Ok but nevertheless, assume that lim f(z) exists as |z| -> infinity. It is still not clear to me how to obtain the existence of the series expansion for non-trivial domains of definition of f.

Are you asking about the case where $f$ is analytic in a deleted neighbourhood of $\infty$, or where it is not?

When it is not, i.e. $f$ is analytic in some domain which extend all the way to infinity in some areas but is not a complete deleted neighborhood of $\infty$. An example is the upper half-space. If I apply the conformal mapping $\frac{1}{z}$ then the upper half-space turns into the lower half-space and $\infty$ turns into $0$. But then the question is why I can have a power series representation around $0$.

If a power series around $0$ converges anywhere other than $0$, then it converges to an analytic function in a neighbourhood of $0$.

A function that isn't analytic in a neighbourhood of $0$ could have a power series that doesn't converge but is an asymptotic series.

My god I was never aware of the difference between an asymptotic power series representation and actual power series representation! As I understand the former is weaker, and in my case it would correspond to showing that for any fixed partial sum if I take $z$ to infinify then |f(z) - partial sum| becomes small.
